# How to aggregate successive SE(3) into one net SE(3) transform

Tags: numpy, transformation, projection, rigid-bodies

I am working on rendering a point cloud an image from nuScenes dataset. The transformation between the LiDAR and camera are denoted by 4 successive transformations which i am trying to aggregate into one. The following code snippet shows how I am trying to aggregate.

```
 # Rotation

firstTransform = np.matmul(transform2[0:3,0:3], transform1[0:3,0:3])
senondTransform = np.matmul(transform3[0:3,0:3], firstTransform)
netTransformation[0:3,0:3] = np.matmul(transform4[0:3,0:3], senondTransform)

# Translation

netTransformation[0:3,3] = cs_record_egoframe_cameraSE3[0:3,3] + 
                           poserecord_image_timeSE3[0:3,3] -
                           poserecord_pointsensor_egoposeSE3[0:3,3] - 
                           cs_record_sweep_timeSE3[0:3,3]
```

The sign of the translations seem to correct. But unfortunately I am not getting the desired results. Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

For reference, here is the equivalent code from nuscenes-devkit

```
 # Points live in the point sensor frame. So they need to be transformed via global to the image plane.
    # First step: transform the pointcloud to the ego vehicle frame for the timestamp of the sweep.
    cs_record = self.nusc.get('calibrated_sensor', pointsensor['calibrated_sensor_token'])
    pc.rotate(Quaternion(cs_record['rotation']).rotation_matrix)
    pc.translate(np.array(cs_record['translation']))

    # Second step: transform from ego to the global frame.
    poserecord = self.nusc.get('ego_pose', pointsensor['ego_pose_token'])
    pc.rotate(Quaternion(poserecord['rotation']).rotation_matrix)
    pc.translate(np.array(poserecord['translation']))

    # Third step: transform from global into the ego vehicle frame for the timestamp of the image.
    poserecord = self.nusc.get('ego_pose', cam['ego_pose_token'])
    pc.translate(-np.array(poserecord['translation']))
    pc.rotate(Quaternion(poserecord['rotation']).rotation_matrix.T)

    # Fourth step: transform from ego into the camera.
    cs_record = self.nusc.get('calibrated_sensor', cam['calibrated_sensor_token'])
    pc.translate(-np.array(cs_record['translation']))
    pc.rotate(Quaternion(cs_record['rotation']).rotation_matrix.T)
```